# Is playing with a 3v battery dangerous?

Tags: batteries, motor

Alright so I'm young and bored and decided to get some 3v vibration motors and CR2032 LiCB batteries and mess around with them for experimentation purposes. I don't play with electronics very often so I probably made some stupid mistakes, but I'm unsure exactly what I've done wrong (I'd like to know this for the future, when I acquire stronger motors/batteries/general electronics).

Here are the more ... questionable activities I engaged in:

1. Hot gluing motors to plastic. I wanted to see the strength of vibration through hard plastic so I hot glued the motors to there (with the glue gun on high)
2. Taped, with painter's tape, wire leads from motors the battery terminals, also held them there with my fingers (holding on both sides) consistently, a fair few times
3. Taped wire leads from motors to the battery terminals the wrong way (negative to positive terminal and vice versa)
4. Connected the leads of multiple (3) motors (of the same and different types - all 3v though) to the same battery
5. Used the entire battery in an order of ... 45 minutes or so.

Which of these were alright and which should I not repeat?

Comment: First of all, it's not smart to play with the stuff like that. Today you're okay, tomorrow you connect something the wrong and unlucky way and things can smoke up. Or even combust. And you don't want to mess with combusting batteries. Second of all, there are no "just vibration motors". Every device is different and has different specs and can survive different levels of your torture. Get documentation for them and don't do anything that doesn't correlate with the datasheet. This is all jokes and fun until it's not.

Comment: @Ilya I acquired my motors off of amazon cuz I didn't want to wait to ship from an actual electronics provider ... amazon doesn't have datasheets.

Comment: They have name, some specs, something. There is no "just a motor" item there. It has special name which describes its function, voltage rating, at least something.

Comment: "Linear vibration motor, 3v, 19k rpm, [no amperage rating], 6mmx14mm", also "button vibration motor, 3v, 12k rpm, [also no amperage rating, probably should have connected it to a multimeter], 10mmx3mm", both DC

Comment: Keep playing. Do not listen to people who try to make you feel bad about it. If possible, be prepared to put out a fire in case you accidentally start a fire. Also, try to avoid breathing smoke from electronics. This is more general advice as you progress to bigger and more dangerous things. Have fun. The world has more than enough boring people in it already.

Comment: @mkeith learned my lesson with solder fumes a while ago; I now have a fume hood :) thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4):

The biggest hazard you might encounter with a CR2032 battery is if you toss it in a fire, smash it or swallow it. Otherwise you face no danger from the 3V they put out.

It’s not wise to short them, but they’re not as dangerous as other lithium batteries like the lithium polymer (LiPo) type used in smartphones and laptops.

This is because CR2032 cells have internal resistance that limits their current, so they don’t immediately overheat and explode like, say, a shorted-out *unprotected* LiPo.

If you just want an easy voltage source to play around with, you can get battery holders for two AA batteries. These batteries will last much longer and be less expensive than the CR2032.

Comment: nice, thank you

Comment: If you short it while touching the terminals or wire you could also burn yourself, but it won’t kill you.

Comment: @Ryan Would putting leads from multiple motors on the battery terminals short the battery or just provide less current to them (I'm assuming same terminals ~= in parallel ... if not, what's the proper way to do it)?

Comment: @mechytechy no that wouldn’t short it.